# Access custom attribute on method from Castle Windsor interceptor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to access a custom attribute applied to a method within a castle interceptor, e.g.:

```
[MyCustomAttribute(SomeParam = "attributeValue")]
public virtual MyEntity Entity { get; set; }
```

using the following code:

```
internal class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true) != null)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The interceptor is firing OK when the method is called but this code does not return the custom attribute. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what version of DynamicProxy are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out - it is because of the difference between the property and the method. It is the get_ method that triggers the interceptor, and this is not decorated with the attribute of the parent property.

Answer (score 4):

Try `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(...)` static method for this. It's bizarre but these two methods return different results sometimes for some strange reason.

Comment: Thanks mate, I ran into this bug today and was going bananas until your post saved the day. The static method works, just as you say, and so does the generic `GetCustomAttribute<type>()`. Unfortunately, the latter is only present in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Just saw that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx states that _"This method ignores the inherit parameter for properties and events. To search the inheritance chain for attributes on properties and events, use the appropriate overloads of the Attribute.GetCustomAttributes method."_ Very inconsistent design IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
private static Attribute getMyCustomAttribute(IInvocation invocation)
{
   var methodInfo = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
   if (methodInfo == null)
   {
      methodInfo = invocation.Method;
   }
   return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(methodInfo, typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
}
```

Comment: var methodInfo = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget ?? invocation.Method;